# Chain several routes in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

How can I get these 2 routes (languages, amdin) to work.. alone admin, or language will work but together they will fail :(

```
; Admin route
resources.router.routes.admin.type = Zend_Controller_Router_Route
resources.router.routes.admin.route = ":admin"
resources.router.routes.admin.reqs.admin = "admin"

; Language route
resources.router.routes.language.type = Zend_Controller_Router_Route
resources.router.routes.language.route = ":language"
resources.router.routes.language.reqs.language = "^(nl|en)$"
resources.router.routes.language.defaults.language = "nl"

; Default route chain
resources.router.routes.default.type = Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Chain
resources.router.routes.default.chain = "language, admin, defaultmodule"
```

Comment: hey Chris, i m stuck in same situation , how it got solve. if you can share would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, of course.
These routes are overlapping, while they should have been different.

```
; Admin route
...
resources.router.routes.admin.route = "admin/:admin"
...
```